# Reference to member variable broken after adding another instance to the same vector

Tags: c++, reference, stdvector

Consider the following code:

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int& xref = x;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Point> points;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Point p;
        p.x = i;
        points.push_back(p);
        assert (points[0].x == points[0].xref);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The assertion fails on the second iteration. Why?

I'm using the GNU C++ compiler. The problem occurs with all of the standards I've tested:

- c++11
- c++14
- c++17
- gnu++11
- gnu++14
- gnu++17

Every element's `xref` seems to reference the last added element's `x` instead of its own, as can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/H4wCszxp

Comment: x is not an reference and is not intialized with the new value of i

Comment: @JakeFreeman Please elaborate. I never claimed `x` was a reference. And it is set to `i` in the statement `p.x = i;`

Comment: Correct because on the second iteration what using push_back the memory location of point[0].x changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you push an object into a vector, you make a copy †.

When you copy a reference (that is the member), the new reference will refer to the same object as the one it was copied from. So, if you copy a `Point p` into a `Point copy`, then `copy::xref` will refer to `p.x`, because that's what `p.xref` refers to.

So, all `Point` objects that are within the vector are copies of the `Point p` automatic variables that were constructed within the scope of the loop. And therefore all of those objects in the vector refer to the `int` objects that are the member of the automatic variable `p`. None of them refer to their own `x` member.

During first iteration this is fine, because `points[0].xref` refers to an existing `p.x`, which also has the same value as `points[0].x`. But at the end of that iteration, the automatic variable `p` (whose member the `points[0].xref` refers to) is destroyed. At this point `points[0].xref` is a dangling reference that no longer refers to a valid object. In the next iteration the reference is used. Using a dangling reference has undefined behaviour.

---

If you wish to access *this* object, then use `this` pointer. If you want to store a reference to an object, then don't expect a copy of that reference to refer to another object. Avoid storing a reference (or a pointer) to an object that has shorter lifetime than the object that holds the reference.

---

† ... or make a move when you push an rvalue. You don't push an rvalue, and a copy is exactly the same thing as move for `Point`), so this is an irrelevant detail.

Comment: Makes sense. So if you want to maintain a reference to a member variable, you need to define an appropriate copy constructor, which would look like this for the example I gave in the question: `Point(const Point& src) : x(src.x), xref(x) {}`

Comment: @user2623008 that would indeed work. However, there's rarely a reason to have a reference that always refers to a member, because you can always find that member with `this` without using any reference.

Comment: @user2623008 Forgot to mention: you would also have to define the appropriate copy assignment operator. And also the move constructor / assignment operator to cover all cases.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because when the point is inserted into the vector it get copied, and the reference points to the original value.
Eg. this work fine:

```
int main() {
    Point p;
    p.x = 100;
    assert (p.x == p.xref);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you might have a small misunderstanding of how the declaration `int& xref = x;` works. It's simply a default initialisation.

- It does not guarantee that `xref` it will always be constructed to reference `x`. The default copy constructor will copy the source instance's xref.
- Furthermore you can change the xref binding with an initialiser list.

I'll first illustrate with a simplified version of what you're seeing, and follow-up with a modified version of your code. I'll wrap up with a tweak to your `Point` object that will get it to behave as you expect.

```
int main()
{
  Point p;
  p.x = 1;
  std::cout << &p.x << "(" << p.x << ") " << &p.xref << "(" << p.xref << ")\n";

  Point p2 = p;
  std::cout << &p2.x << "(" << p2.x << ") " << &p2.xref << "(" << p2.xref << ")\n";
  p2.x = 2;
  std::cout << &p2.x << "(" << p2.x << ") " << &p2.xref << "(" << p2.xref << ")\n";

  Point p3 {3, p2.x};
  std::cout << &p3.x << "(" << p3.x << ") " << &p3.xref << "(" << p3.xref << ")\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
//The in value of p.x and p.xref are in the same location
0x7ffde0450670(1) 0x7ffde0450670(1)
//p2 is initialised as a copy of p
//So p2.x has its own location but value is copied
//and p2.xref refers to the same location as p.xref (and hence p.x)
0x7ffde0450680(1) 0x7ffde0450670(1)
//Therefore updating p2.x doesn't affect p2.xref
0x7ffde0450680(2) 0x7ffde0450670(1)
//All members of p3 are initialised with initialiser list
//p3.x has its own location
//p3.xref is assigned location of p2.x
0x7ffde0450690(3) 0x7ffde0450680(2)
```

Graphically this looks like:

```
p-----> +-------------------------+
     +->| x = 1                   |
     |  | xref = 0x7ffde0450670 --|--+
     |  +-------------------------+  |
     |-------------------------------+
     |
     +--------------------------------+
p2-----> +-------------------------+  |
     +-> | x = 2                   |  |
     |   | xref = 0x7ffde0450670 --|--+
     |   +-------------------------+  
     +--------------------------------+
p3-----> +-------------------------+  |
         | x = 3                   |  |
         | xref = 0x7ffde0450680 --|--+
         +-------------------------+
```

---

Modifying your code slightly:

```
std::vector<Point> points;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    Point p;
    p.x = i;
    points.push_back(p);
    std::cout << i << " " << &p << "\n";
    std::cout << &p.x << "(" << p.x << ") " << &p.xref << "(" << p.xref << ")\n";
    std::cout << &points[0].x << "(" << points[0].x << ") " << &points[0].xref << "(" << points[0].xref << ")\n";
}
```

Sample output:

```
0 0x7fffa80e0840
0x7fffa80e0840(0) 0x7fffa80e0840(0)
0x55bd4ff52c30(0) 0x7fffa80e0840(0)
//On each iteration p is in the same location
1 0x7fffa80e0840
//So p.x is in the same location
0x7fffa80e0840(1) 0x7fffa80e0840(1)
//And the vector elements are initialised with p
//So each element's xref is the same as p.x and p.xref
0x55bd4ff52c50(0) 0x7fffa80e0840(1)
```

---

Finally, by exercising a little control of the `Point` constructors, you can get it to behave as you expect.

```
struct Point {
  int x;
  int& xref = x;
  Point() = default;
  Point(const Point& p): x(p.x) {}
};
```

The above code does the following:

- It replaces the default copy constructor with one that copies only the value of `x` from source. Therefore `xref` retains its default initialisation.
- As a consequence of defining your own constructor, the default constructor is removed. So now you need to explicitly declare it; fortunately you can specify that default implementation suffices.